# how to open py file in background

Tags: fc

I've been learning Python for a while, but over the last month I've been wondering if it's possible to run a .py file in the background so that its activity can only be seen in the task manager.  Will this work with pyinstaller and auto-py-to-exe?

I tried to find a solution on various Internet resources, but to be honest, I didn’t understand anything.  I think these can be implemented using a console command for the Python terminal, or by changing the extension.  I would be sincerely grateful if someone responds